# Database SQL queries, compare values

Tags: mysql, sql, database

```
CUSTOMER(cid, cname, ccity)
TICKET(tid, cid, pricepaid, milespaid, date)          - cid references CUSTOMER.cid
FLIGHT(fid, deptapc, arrapc, dept, arr, milesgiven) 
deptapc and arrapc reference AIRPORT.apc
FLIGHTTICKET(tid, fid, date) - tid references TICKET.tid and fid references FIGHT.fid
AIRPORT(apc, aname, acity)
```

Output the cid of any customer who has been to every airport in the database. (It is enough to pass through an airport while changing fights, so it does not have to be the final destination).

I write this to show the number of airport that each customer has been to:

```
Select cid,count(cid)
From(SELECT cid, deptapc
FROM CUSTOMER 
Natural join TICKET Natural join FLIGHTTICKET Natural join FLIGHT
UNION
SELECT cid, arrapc
FROM CUSTOMER 
Natural join TICKET Natural join FLIGHTTICKET Natural join FLIGHT)
Group by cid;
```

but I don't know how to compare each value with the total number of airport to see if they are the same

```
Select count(apc) 
From AIRPORT
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

easy you just use subquery as you already did in FROM :

```
SELECT cid, 
       Count(cid), 
       ( Count(cid) = (SELECT Count(apc) 
                       FROM   airport) ) AS result 
FROM  (SELECT cid, 
              deptapc 
       FROM   customer 
              natural JOIN ticket 
              natural JOIN flightticket 
             natural JOIN flight 
       UNION 
       SELECT cid, 
              arrapc 
       FROM   customer 
              natural JOIN ticket 
              natural JOIN flightticket 
              natural JOIN flight) 
GROUP  BY cid;
```